# Why do I receive the error "Args didn't Validate"?

Tags: powershell

I am currently attempting to write a powershell script that will:

1.) Grab a folder name from a specified directory.

2.) Store that folder name into a variable `$i.Name`

3.) Place that Variable into my cmdline sequence with params and run the .exe.

**Here is the script I starting whipping up:**

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Force
#copy directories and files to new destination    
#cpi C:\localApps\AutomationTest\Analysis\2016\*  C:\localApps\AutomationTest\Loading -Recurse
Get-ChildItem C:\localApps\AutomationTest\Loading | where {$_.PSIsContainer} | Write-Host
foreach($i in Get-ChildItem C:\localApps\AutomationTest\Loading)
{
   if ($i.PSisContainer) {$i.Name}

   $CMD = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Analysis 4.2\LoadAnalysis4.exe'
   $arg1 = '-database:"Data Source=ABC-SQL-DB123\MSSQLSERVER_DB;Initial Catalog=Analysis4;Automated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultsSets=True;Application Name=LoadAnalysis4.exe"'
   $arg2 = '-directory:"C:\localApps\AutomationTest\Loading\$i"'
   $arg3 = '-wsdir:"C:\Automation\AnalysisWSFolder"'
   $arg4 = '-tempdir:"C:\tmp"'
   $arg5 = '-minws'
   $arg6 = '-name:"$i"'
   $arg7 = '-config:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Analysis 4.2\AnalysisLoadConfigs\stnd-with-abc-testing.xml"'

   & $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5 $arg6 $arg7

}
```

**Here are the results I received:**

```
TestFolder1  
TestFolder1
Args didn't Validate
Error: The following unknown parameters were specified: 'Source=ABC-SQL-DB123\MSSQLSERVER_DB;Initial';
'Catalog=Analysis4;Automated'; 'Security=True;MultipleActiveResultsSets=True;Application';
'Name=LoadAnalysis4.exe'; 'Files'; '(x86)\Analysis'; '4.2\AnalysisLoadConfigs\stnd-with-abc-testing.xml'

LoadAnalysis4.exe completed, elapsed: 00:00:00.123456
```

It seems as if I have a spacing issue in my Args. Looking for a good way to get these Args Validated and script working.

**I wanted to wrap this question up. So here is what ended up working for a newb like me who rarely uses PowerShell....**

```
 foreach($i in Get-ChildItem C:\localApps\AutomationTest\Loading)
 {
    if ($i.PSisContainer) {$i.Name}

    $CMD = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Analysis 4.2\LoadAnalysis4.exe'
    $arg1 = "-database:Data Source=ABC-SQL-DB123\MSSQLSERVER_DB;InitialCatalog=Analysis4;Automated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultsSets=True;Application Name=LoadAnalysis4.exe"
    $arg2 = "-directory:C:\localApps\AutomationTest\Loading\$i"
    $arg3 = "-wsdir:C:\Automation\AnalysisWSFolder"
    $arg4 = "-tempdir:C:\tmp"
    $arg5 = "-minws"
    $arg6 = "-name:$i"
    $arg7 = "-config:C:\Program Files (x86)\Analysis  4.2\AnalysisLoadConfigs\stnd-with-abc-testing.xml"


    & $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5 $arg6 $arg7

 }
```

I put `""` around all of the params and `''` around the `$CMD exe`.

Comment: That seems to be the powershell external command equivalent to linux shell "word splitting". The embedded space was seen as an argument splitting space and not part of a string.

Comment: @PetSerAl   I typed in `get-host|Select-Object version` and it says 4.0.

Comment: `& $CMD '--%' $arg1 ...`; also single quoted string does not expand variables.

Comment: Okay, I was working off an example I found referencing `// The Call Operator &`  I found this article [PowerShell Call Operator](https://com2kid.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/powershell-call-operator-using-an-array-of-parameters-to-solve-all-your-quoting-problems/) perhaps this link will help me.

Comment: If you want to start a process with arguments, Try using `Start-Process $cmd -ArgumentList $args`

Comment: @PetSerAl Won't that `--%` stop `$Arg1` from expanding?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician it is `'--%'`, not `--%`.

Comment: Okay, so I am a little confused. What exactly does `'--%'` do? Does this fix my spacing issues or should I look to use `Join`?  Also I did read that `'` single quotes will display the literal variable, while `"` double quotes will display the value of the variable.

Comment: `--%`    Syntax   PowerShell_commands  non-powershell_arguments/expressions
The stop-parsing symbol (--%), introduced in PowerShell 3.0, directs PowerShell to refrain from interpreting any further input on the line as PowerShell commands or expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing arguments as an array:

```
foreach($i in Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\localApps\AutomationTest\Loading')
{
    if($i.PSisContainer){$i.Name}

    $CMD = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Analysis 4.2\LoadAnalysis4.exe'
    $Arguments = @(
        '-database:Data Source=ABC-SQL-DB123\MSSQLSERVER_DB;InitialCatalog=Analysis4;Automated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultsSets=True;Application Name=LoadAnalysis4.exe',
        "-directory:C:\localApps\AutomationTest\Loading\$i",
        '-wsdir:C:\Automation\AnalysisWSFolder',
        '-tempdir:C:\tmp',
        '-minws',
        "-name:$i",
        '-config:C:\Program Files (x86)\Analysis  4.2\AnalysisLoadConfigs\stnd-with-abc-testing.xml'
    )

    & $CMD $Arguments
}
```

#### Reference:

- [PowerShell and external commands done right](http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/)

Comment: I will try the arguments as an array and also check out that link.

Comment: @Twdeveloper You're supposed to try answer first and accept it if it works later ;).